# How to remove a taxonomy term with an empty required field without having to fill it?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm having a problem while trying to delete a taxonomy term that has an empty required field. To proceed and delete it, I have to fill the empty field to be able to delete it.

How can I remove the taxonomy term without having to fill the empty required field?

For me there is no problem by adding a letter to the field and then delete the taxonomy, but my client is getting crazy with this issue and he is getting me crazy.

Any solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hum, well, how come your client ends with missing required fields in his terms?

Comment: It sounds like one its fields was made required after-the-fact of many terms being entered. Either that, or they're being added programmatically where they're bypassing validation.

Answer (score 1):

I usually write out code when I need to bypass validation for deletion. You can use [taxonomy_term_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_delete/7) to remove the items and bypass validation:

```
$tids = array(); //Add your term ids that you need deleted in the array
foreach($tids as $tid) {
  taxonomy_term_delete($tid);
}
```